# Object detection boxes are lost at second evaluation step

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, tensorboard

I'm a beginner with Tensorflow 1.4.0 and I'm trying to perform my first training + evaluation process on an object detection model. What I'm seeing is something weird when looking at the output of the evaluation steps.

Here is the steps I made. First, it's worth to say that my goal is to detect two different kind of shapes in very particular scientific images. They are under a kind of "copyright" so I just can show a simplified version of them (made by hand). Just keep in mind that the original ones are way more detailed.

A raw example of input image, see it as a repeated pattern (there is always a grid in the background) with some particular shapes in random positions.

[image]

1. As you can see I want to train the model to detect 2 classes: "round" shapes (class A) and "irregular" shapes (class B).
2. I used [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to generate labels for both the classes in XML format. In general, I've labeled 168 images (**960x720 RGB, PNG**) ending up with a total of 800 boxes (a single image might have multiple A/B shapes in it).

[image]

3. I've also prepared a smaller dataset for evaluation composed of 10 new images and 150 labels. This time **the images are bigger than the others** in the train dataset (but they are not "resized", simply the viewport is larger so there could be more events in each input). We are talking about **1920x1440 RGB, PNG** images.
4. Then I converted the XMLs for both the datasets into two `.tfrecord` files (there are some scripts around GitHub for this).
5. Then I prepared all the other input files for Tensorflow:

Label map file:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'shape_a'
  display_name: 'Shape A'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: 'shape_b'
  display_name: 'Shape B'
}
```

Config file (adapted from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs). As you can see I've chosen the faster_rcnn_inception_v2 and I tried to train it from scratch (because of the nature of those images, that are way different from the ones used in the pretrained models). Most of the parameters are kept as they are in the repository.

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 2
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 720
        max_dimension: 960
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.5
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  from_detection_checkpoint: false
  # fine_tune_checkpoint: "./run/train/modelXXXXXX.ckpt"

  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {}
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_vertical_flip {}
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness { max_delta: 0.15 }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./train.tfrecord"
  }
  label_map_path: "./label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 10
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
  eval_interval_secs: 300
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "./eval.tfrecord"
  }
  label_map_path: "./label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

6. Finally, I run Tensorflow by calling the https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/train.py script. By running on a notebook Nvidia Quadro GPU, performances are around 0.600 sec/step. There are no errors in the console but the first thing I see is that the Loss seems to converge to 0.4 and stay there in relatively few (?) steps:

[image]

7. When around 500 steps, I've also started the evaluation script (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/eval.py) on the CPU. It runs every 5 minutes (`eval_interval_secs: 300`) and I can see the output on Tensorboard.

Here is the problem. The first evaluation is relative to the checkpoint at step #0, so the output images are a bunch of randomly displaced boxes, and this should be normal. One fact is that **only boxes for the first A class are present**.
Then, from the second evaluation (around step #1000) and so on **all the output images have no detection anymore**! No A/B class boxes are drawn and nothing show up until I decide to stop everything (step #10000).

I was expecting to continue seeing detection, even if with errors.

I have many questions and I've probably made clear mistakes in my flow (my knowledge is still very limited):

- Is it really a strange behavior what I'm seeing on loss and evaluation outputs?
- What techniques can I use to check if I did some conceptual mistakes in data preparation?
- Can I debug what's happening under the hood during training?
- How about the Tensorflow config file? Is there something wrong there?

A note: I've also tried that same thing using other models like ssd_*, but behavior is the same.

Comment: i am having kind of similar problem. Were you able to come to any conclusion about this problem?

Comment: Anything updated for this issue? I also hit a similar issue that some obvious targets are lost for object detection